# golang, postgresql короткое представление даты

Tags: postgresql, golang, дата, select

Есть таблица j_nar

```
journal=# select * from j_nar;
id | id_patient | number_nar | date_open_nar | date_close_nar 
----+------------+------------+---------------+----------------
34 |         33 | 777        | 2017-03-01    | 2017-03-05
35 |         34 | 111        | 2017-03-18    | 2017-03-18
(2 rows)
journal=#
```

В таблице имеются поля

date_open_nar type date

date_close_nar type date

Делаю запрос к базе и передаю на в response следующем образом:

**Модель**

```
package models

import (
"time"
)

type Add_rows struct {
 Id        int64
 Fam       string
 Name      string
 Lastname  string
 Datebirth string
 Phone     string
 Homeadres string
 Numberud  string
 Lgotcat   string
 // Lgotcat_1[]  string
 Fiovrach       string
 DateInvitation string
 DateNar        string
 Numbernar      string
 Fioreg         string
 Comment        string
 NumberNar      string
 DateOpenNar    time.Time
 DateCloseNar   time.Time
}
```

**Функция**

```
type currentIdListNar struct {
id string
}

 var currentId currentIdListNar

func ListNar(w http.ResponseWriter, rnd render.Render) {
    const shortForm = "2006-01-02"
    query := "SELECT number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar WHERE 
    id_patient = " + currentId.id + ""
    rows := db.Select(query)
    bks := make([]*models.Add_rows, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
       bk := new(models.Add_rows)
       rows.Scan(&bk.Name, &bk.DateOpenNar, &bk.DateCloseNar)
       bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    for _, bk := range bks {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s %s %s \n", bk.Name, bk.DateOpenNar, 
        bk.DateCloseNar)
    }
}
```

В итоге в html таблице, получаю "полное" преставление (формат) времени т.е:

2017-03-18  00:00:00    +0000

Объясните пожалуйста, или запрос к базе нужно менять, или обрезать уже со стороны сервера до нужного мне формата (2017-03-18) и отдавать его в response

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тип Time в go, можно парсить сами переменные даты: Небольшой пример:

```
func FormatDate(Time time.Time) string {
    return Time.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
}
```

Либо функцией Date:

```
func GetTime() time.Time {
    t := time.Now()
    return time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.Second(), 0, time.UTC)
}
```

В документации много разных функций, так что только руками резать, так как формат Time по умолчанию идет со временем.
А вообще обрезай в back-end и сохраняй в строку. Далее уже для отображения или передачи в какие нить поля на фронте, формат string вполне подходит. 
Есть еще функция String() - но я уже не помню почему я ее не использую в разработке:D

Comment: я к этому склонялся (резать на back-end), просто думал, что это как-то не правильно.

Comment: А выбора нет =)